# How do I highlight an entire row in excel if there is an error =N/A

Tags: excel

I want to use conditional formatting in excel but am struggling to do so.
I do not wish to use excel VBA

Comment: Did you try following this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the range you wish to have formatted.

Choose from the Ribbon
Home->Conditional Formatting->Manage Rules.

Click "New Rule..."

Click "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

Enter the formula

`=ISNA($column_letter_first row_number)`

Something like:

`=ISNA($I1)`

The $ "anchors" the formula to the column and allows the row to move. You want this to ensure the format is applied to the selected range.

Create the format you wish to see for #N/A rows by pressing the "Format..." button.

Bold red text with a light pink background works for me.

Click "OK" twice and then click "Apply"

[image: After clicking "Apply" the range should look like this]

Click "OK" to close the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager dialog.